# Trying to add a submit button which submits state to label

Tags: reactjs

A label is not showing when I click a submit button.

I've tried using ternary operators. I've tried passing the state of the source label to the onClick of the button.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";

class Bankcard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
    this.resetButton = this.resetButton.bind(this);
    this.submitName = this.submitName.bind(this);

    //these functions can be bound in the render! Yay!
    this.state = { cardHolderName: " ", submitButtonState: " ", mode: "view" };
  }

  changeName(e) {
    this.setState({ cardHolderName: e.target.value });
  }

  resetButton() {
    this.setState({ cardHolderName: " " });
  }

  submitName() {
    this.setState({
      submitButtonState: this.state.cardHolderName,
      mode: "view"
    });
  }

  render() {
    const cardDetails = sampleInfo[0];

    return (
      <div className="cssmainbox">
        <InsertName
          onNameChange={this.changeName}
          cardHolderName={this.state.cardHolderName}
        />

        <div className="csslabel">
          <label>{this.state.cardHolderName}</label>
        </div>
        <div className="cssbutton" />

        <ResetButton onResetClick={this.resetButton} />

        <br />
        <br />
        <div className="cssmainnum">{cardDetails.mainnum}</div>
        <br />

        <SubmitButton
          onSubmitClick={this.submitName}
          submitButtonState={this.state.submitButtonState}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const sampleInfo = [
  {
    mainnum: 123456789,
    validthru: "08/19",
    vsc: 1234
  }
];

class InsertName extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="theusersname"
          onChange={this.props.onNameChange}
          value={this.props.cardHolderName}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ResetButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onResetClick}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SubmitButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const view = this.state.mode === "view";
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          value={this.props.cardHolderName}
          onClick={this.props.onNameChange}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
        {view ? null : <p>{this.state.cardHolderName}</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Bankcard />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I want to use a submit button which reads text from a label and then submits it to another label. The destination label must be hidden until the submit button is clicked. 
It's not showing the label no matter how many times I click on that darn Submit button!

Can someone tell me how to write this so it works please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors are:- (1) You are calling wrong clickEvent, it should be onClick (2) With your code pass a function-callback props in  and use callback to invoke Parent function.

```
 <SubmitButton 
    onClick={() => this.submitName()}
    submitButtonState={this.state.submitButtonState}
 />
```